# Hyperplanes in 3 dimensional space over set of real numbers R

Tags: general-topology

Let H1, H2, H3, H4 be 4 hyperplanes in 3 dimensional space over set of real numbers R. The maximum possible number of connected components of (R^3) -(union of H1, H2, H3 and H4)  is 14.  Answer is false but I can't understand question properly and how it is not true please someone help me

Comment: There is a special name for hyperplanes in 3-dimensional space. We call them just "planes".

Comment: Thanks but how it is false?

Answer (score 1):

It should be fairly clear that you get more components when the planes are not parallel than when they are, and when no more than 2 intersect in the same line, and no more than 3 in the same point. (I'll leave verification of this to you.) So assume that those conditions hold.

Any three of the planes intersect in a point. You can match these points 1-1 with the plane not included in the intersection, so there are 4 of them. And they have to be in general position to avoid violating the conditions above. So these points form the vertices of a tetrahedron, each of whose faces lies in one of the four planes, and whose edges are all in the intersections of two of the planes.

The interior of the tetrahedron is one of the components you are counting. The other components are all in contact with the interior through a face, edge or vertex. There are 4 faces, 4 vertices, and 6 edges, and the interior. That is $4 + 4 + 6 + 1 = 15$ components.